# Restricting users to input only numbers in C# windows application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have tried this code to restrict only numbers.It type only numbers and don't make entry when we try to enter characters or any other controls, even it doesnt enter backspace also. how to prevent backspace from it.

```
private void TxtBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
     if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(e.KeyChar.ToString(), "\\d+"))
          e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to _allow_ backspaces?

Comment: e.Handled = "+-.\b0123456789".IndexOf(e.KeyChar) < 0;

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You do not need to use a RegEx in order to test for digits:

```
private void TxtBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
     if (!Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
          e.Handled = true;
}
```

To allow for backspace:

```
private void TxtBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
     if (!(Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back)))
          e.Handled = true;
}
```

If you want to add other allowable keys, look at the [`Keys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx) enumeration and use the approach above.

Comment: this wont work if somebody copy and paste text inside textbox

Answer (score 8):

To allow only numbers in a textbox in a windows application, use

```
private void TxtBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
     if (!(Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back)))
          e.Handled = true;
}
```

This sample code will allow entering numbers and backspace to delete previous entered text.

Answer (score 6):

Use the [Char.IsDigit Method (String, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0t641e58.aspx) method and check out the `NumericTextbox` by Microsoft

[MSDN How to: Create a Numeric Text Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229644%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

put following code in keypress event of your textbox:

```
     private void txtbox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use `Char.IsDigit()` method

Answer (score 0):

Methods Suggested above only prevent user typing anything but number,
but it will fail if user copy and paste some text inside textbox so we also need to check the input on text change event

**Create ontextchangeEvent**

```
 private void TxtBox1_textChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsDigitsOnly(contactText.Text))
        {
            contactText.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }

private bool IsDigitsOnly(string str)
    {
        foreach (char c in str)
        {
            if (c < '0' || c > '9')
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```