# c# Fibonacci calculator issue

Tags: c#, fibonacci, fix-protocol

i am trying to get a working Fibonacci calculator but i am having some issues. as far as i can tell my code is working well, although it crashes when i input a word. i'm unsure how i can get this to work for me so it will only accept numbers. Thanks in advance :D

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void Button_Click1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        //Fibonacci

        string output = String.Empty;



        double result;
        double z = 0;
        double x = 1;
        double y = double.Parse(FibonacciAsText.Text);
        if (double.TryParse(FibonacciAsText.Text, out result))
        {
            if (y == 1)
                output = 1.ToString();
        }
        else if (y == 0)
        {
            output = 0.ToString();
        }
        for (double w = 0; w < y - 1; w++)
        {
            result = z;
            z = x;
            x = result + x;
            output = x.ToString();
        }
        Fibonacci.Text = output;
    }
```

Comment: `double.Parse(FibonacciAsText.Text)` cannot parse word

Comment: `double y = double.Parse(FibonacciAsText.Text);` is the problem. Use tryparse here too.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya when i do that i get the following error "No overload for method 'Tryparse' takes 1 arguments"

Comment: See the answer by Cory. Let us know if that doesn't work.

Comment: See this for wpf : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268552/how-do-i-get-a-textbox-to-only-accept-numeric-input-in-wpf or this for winforms : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590501/restricting-users-to-input-only-numbers-in-c-sharp-windows-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will exit the method and not allow the code to finish:

```
double y;

if (!double.TryParse(FibonacciAsText.Text, out y))
{
    Fibonacci.Text = "N/A";
    return;
}
```

Basically, it's checking to see if you have a valid number. If so, it will set that as y (similar to Parse). If it doesn't succeed though, it will exit the method at "return".

Comment: although now if i input a word after a past number it will still output the past number

Comment: Well, it depends on how your code reads. I can't see the updated code. It shouldn't though as long as the "word" is in the FibonacciAsText textbox

Comment: `private void Button_Click1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            //Fibonacci

            string output = String.Empty;



            double result;
            double z = 0;
            double x = 1;
            double y;

            if (!double.TryParse(FibonacciAsText.Text, out y))
                return;
            
                if (y == 1)
                    output = 1.ToString();`

Comment: http://imgur.com/RZMFUHU   i put in 9 it gave me the output tried fish and it still shows the past output

Comment: Ah, it's because you aren't clearing the past output. After "return" it's not doing anything. Including clearing that textbox. If you want to clear the output, you need to explicitly tell it to. See my update.

Comment: That's much better thanks so much :D ty for the help

Answer (score 0):

You need validate the input first.If you are using a textbox..there should be a setting to accept only numbers.

 Or 
 
In the backend..you can check if the input is a number by using the code below

```
int n;
bool isNumeric = int.TryParse(FibonacciAsText.Text, out n);

if(isNumeric)
{
Your calculator code
}
```